# Graphing the value with x axis = Year, Y axis = over-single, and Bracket being the line

Tags: python, matplotlib, pivot-table, data-science, data-modeling

I want the x axis being Year, Y axis being over-single, and the line being bracket. The 20 lines is seperate by year YYYY.00, decimal 0.XX, then float.
range of years is 2018-1949. The brackets varies from a min of 2 to max of 25.

1. 2018.0   0.10    0.0
2. 2018.0   0.12    9525.0
3. 2018.0   0.22    38700.0
4. 2018.0   0.24    82500.0
5. 2018.0   0.32    157500.0
6. 2018.0   0.35    200000.0
7. 2018.0   0.37    500000.0
8. 2017.0   0.10    0.0
9. 2017.0   0.15    9325.0
10. 2017.0  0.25    37950.0
11. 2017.0  0.28    91900.0
12. 2017.0  0.33    191650.0
13. 2017.0  0.35    416700.0
14. 2017.0  0.40    418400.0
15. 2016.0  0.10    0.0
16. 2016.0  0.15    9275.0
17. 2016.0  0.25    37650.0
18. 2016.0  0.28    91150.0
19. 2016.0  0.33    190150.0
20. 2016.0  0.35    413350.0
21. 2016.0  0.40    415050.0

plt.plot(TaxB_Over_Yr_three). 
The problem is that the number of brackets changes. For example. .40 exists for year 2017-2010, but it doesn't exists anymore for 2008. So I have to make a new line graph for when the number of brackets changes.

I cleaned the data such that only three columns exists. But I am stuck showing the graph.

```
    TaxB_Over_Yr_app = taxBracket49P[['Year', 'Bracket-single', 'over- 
    single']]
    TaxB_Over_Yr_three=TaxB_Over_Yr_app.dropna(inplace=False)
```

I attempted to group this by year and brackets? But I want to keep value, because I want to graph it over Y-axis. I feel like group-by is used with .count()

```
    all_brackets = TaxB_Over_Yr_three.set_index(['Bracket-single','Year','over-single']).sort_index()
```

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/990R2.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
    MeanOfBracket=TaxB_Over_Yr_three.pivot_table(index='Year', values='over-single', aggfunc='mean')
```

I decided to just use the mean then graph.